# Physical meaning of $SdT$

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

Consider a thermodynamic classical closed system.
Due to the First and Second laws of thermodynamics, we know that $dU=\delta Q-\delta W=TdS-PdV$, and we could assign to $\delta Q=TdS$ the meaning of exchanged heat.

But what physical meaning could we assign to $SdT$ appearing, e.g., in the expression for a reversible Helmholtz free energy variation, $dA=-SdT-PdV$?

Answer (score 2):

**Simple & short answer:**

Consider the constant V case (say, you have a fixed size container of a gas): The $dA$ then is given by
$$dA = -SdT$$
Thus $SdT$ :  For a fixed volume container, how much free energy will decrease by increasing the temparature of the system.